# Tomcat6 Teamcity 5.x WAR deployment DB errors

Tags: tomcat, apache2, teamcity

I'm trying to deploy Teamcity to my Tomcat server [fronted by Apache2]. However, when I try to access Teamcity I get the following DB error. I am wanting it to use the internal DB and it was working fine when using the installation that comes bundled with Tomcat6, but now I've tried to decouple it it is failing.

```
SQL error when doing: Connecting to HSQLDB
SQL exception: The database is already in use by another process: lockFile: org.hsqldb.persist.LockFile@d54a1b4d[file =/etc/tomcat6/.BuildServer/system/buildserver.lck, exists=false, locked=false, valid=false, ] method: openRAF reason: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /etc/tomcat6/.BuildServer/system/buildserver.lck (No such file or directory)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you tried to deploy TeamCity's war file.
To fix the problem, you have to deploy not the war file, but expanded TeamCity.war directory.
Otherwise, you may deploy both war and unpacked war, and this will lead to the error.